# request generated by hibernate non conform to written request

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

there is something crazy that's happening to me. I work on a spring boot hibernate project that was generated with Jhipster. I made a simple JPQL request that is like the following

```
select item from ItemObject item where (item.ins between :dateBegin and :dateEnd) or (item.mod between :dateBegin and :dateEnd)
```

I put show_sql = true and can see the request generated by Hibernate. First the right request generated by Hibernate is displayed in the console window. But after one second a huge request (several dozen of page) is generated and the result interminable (considering the length of the request and the time it takes). It's totally crazy. I have never seen that. I must add that this request was working well almost instantaneous a few days ago. Can you help me ? I cannot show you the huge request displayed because I am not at work, but I just ask you if you have already seen that. So don't rate me badly for the post

Comment: Wait to be at work, and to be able to post the necessary information: the code you're using, the query being executed, the relevant entities.

Comment: Hello, I put logging on hibernate and it prints hundreds of line as the following

Comment: 2020-01-20 09:21:57.688 DEBUG 10142 --- [XNIO-2 task-1] tributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter : Converted value on extraction: null -> null

Answer (score 0):

I put the following logging parameters

```
logging:
    file: logs/application-test.log
    level:
        ROOT: DEBUG
        com.package.vol: INFO
        io.github.jhipster: DEBUG
        org:
          hibernate: 
            SQL:
              TRACE
            type:
               descriptor:
                  sql:
                    BasicBinder:
                      TRACE
```

And the log show that it generates many requests. for example ItemObject (table0) is linked to Object1 ( table1) Object2 (table2) etc.... and it generates the request

```
select tb1.property1, .........., tb1.property50 
from table1 tb1
left outer join table0 on ...
left outer join table2 on ....
.........
left outer join table10 on ...
where tb1.item_id = ?
```

and this for each table linked to table0, that is table1, table2 and so on

Comment: I have a huge hint : When I use this request in the same condition with the same input but from another method, it takes 2,5 seconds and no issues

Answer (score 0):

I will explain you in which case it passes. Here is my model:

```
       MainObject----ItemObject------------Property1Object
                         |             |---Property2Object
                         |             |---Property3Object
                       -----           |---Property4Object
                       | | |
                       Assoc
                       | | |
                      PaObject
```

I remind you that the aim is to execute the following request without issue

```
select item from ItemObject item where (item.ins between :dateBegin and :dateEnd) or (item.mod between :dateBegin and :dateEnd)
```

If, before executing the previous request I pass the 2 following steps, there is no isuue, and I don't know why

STEP 1 : make a request on MainObject to get all these objects that have been    modified or inserted. This step is not mandatory, but it is a preparation step for STEP2. STEP2 is the code that make the request pass without issue

STEP2: From the STEP1, I get a `List<MainObject>` mainObjectsList . So I apply the following code :

```
List<CustomObject> customObjects = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
for (MainObject mainObject : mainObjectsList) {
      customObjects.addAll(constructCustomObjectFromMainObject(mainObject));
}
```

With CustomObject which is the following

```
public class CustomObject    {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;

    private String itemProperty1;
    private String itemProperty2;
    private String itemProperty3;
    private String itemProperty4;
    List<PaObject> paObjectData;
    private Property1Object  property1Object;
    private Property2Object  property2Object;
    private Property3Object  property3Object;
    private Property4Object  property4Object;
}
```

and the constructCustomObjectFromMainObject  method

```
    private  List<CustomObject> constructCustomObjectFromMainObject(MainObject mainObject) {
        List<CustomObject> customObjectList = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
        for (ItemObject item : mainObject.getItems()) {
            customObjectList.add(constructCustomObject(item, true, true, true, true));
        }
        return customObjectList;
    }

   private CustomObject constructCustomObject(ItemObject item, boolean property1Flag, boolean property2Flag, boolean property3Flag, boolean property4Flag) {
        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
        customObject.setItemProperty1(item.getProperty1());
        customObject.setItemProperty2(item.getProperty2());
        customObject.setItemProperty3(item.getProperty3());
        customObject.setItemProperty4(item.getProperty4());
        Set<Assoc> assocSet = item.getAssoc();
        List<PaObject> paObjectList = new ArrayList<PaObject>();
        for (Assoc assoc : assocSet) {
          paObjectList.add(assoc.getPaObject());
        }
        customObject.setpaObjectList(paObjectList);
        if (property1Flag) {
            customObject.setProperty1Object(item.getProperty1Object());
        }
        if (property2Flag) {
            customObject.setProperty2Object(item.getProperty2Objects());
        }
        if (property3Flag) {
            customObject.setProperty3Object(item.getProperty3Object());
        }
        if (property4Flag) {
            customObject.setProperty4Object(new DataConverter().toProperty4Object(item));
        }

        return customObject;
    }
```

I sum up : when STEP2 is executed, my aim request pass without any issue